# .htaccess rewrite entire URL without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I manage a frontend site in one server (cPanel and all the stuff), and a webapp for users in an AWS ec2 instance under Apache, with another domain. Redirect a frontend subdomain to the ec2 instance subdomain is quite easy; but i need the user navigation bar keep the address of the original domain. I've been trying some common .htaccess rewrite configurations without success.

Frontend URL used to redirect to AWS ec2

```
https://elearning.domain1.com/
```

Webapp real URL used in the cPanel redirect subdomain config

```
https://elearning.domain2.com/app/view
```

No problem with the redirection, but the user address bar show the 'domain2' address, so, i create a .htaccess in /app/view directory, and try several not working configurations, the last one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^elearning.domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://elearning.domain1.com/:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L]
```

Can the rewrite mod do this or i'm trying to do something incorrect?

Comment: If I understand your description correct then both domains are served from separate systems. That means you cannot achieve what you ask with rewriting. You will need to setup a reverse proxy in the frontend server. Take a look at the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives the apache proxy module offers. Or you can use the proxy module within the rewriting module by means of the `P` flag. Again: see the documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks, it`s right, two different servers. The problem is that the frontend is hosted in a share server without access to general apache configuration, only limited cPanel DNS zone editor. I can do anything in the ec2 instance, but not in the frontend; and if i understand right the reverse proxy function, i need do that in the frontend making it work like a 'pass server'.
I'm stuck, sadly.

Comment: Correct, you need to setup a proxy server inside your frontend domain. Check if the proxy modulies are loaded (you will get a syntax error if not...) and use the `P` flag as mentioned. That will work in a shared http server _if the proxy module is loaded_ ...